# edit grub after motherboard replacment

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently swap my motherboard and have difficulty booting into Ubuntu. My setup is as follow:

> I have four hard drives:
>   2 ssd which contain a Window 10 and Ubuntu install respectively.
>   2 hdd which are used for storage, one for each of the installed system (one is the D drive in window and the other is mounted as /data in Ubuntu).

Currently when I boot, grub is displayed and I can boot and use Windows. However if I choose the Ubuntu option, I get an error. I was eventually able to boot into Ubuntu after manually editing the options for booting into Ubuntu (Advanced options) but after rebooting it appears that these edits are not permanent.

I am honestly not sure what edit(s) allowed me to boot into Ubuntu in the first place and I am looking for a permanent fix.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

Comment: What's the error that you see? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`. What brand are your SSDs? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: You may just need a full reinstall of grub, or just a few settings. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Did you reinstall drives in same SATA port number? UEFI or BIOS installs?

Comment: @oldfred It is a BIOS install as my old motherboard only supported that method. My new motherboard support both options and I had to set its bios to legacy mode (BIOS) so that GRUB show up at all. The problem is for sure that I did not reinstall the drives in the same SATA port. The first ssd with the window+grub is in the 1st port, identical to the previous setup therefore GRUB appears and window is able to boot.

Comment: Back when I still had XP in 2010, I kept XP on a MBR drive but started converting all other drives to gpt with a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. Then when Windows converted to only UEFI on new vendor installed systems, I started adding an ESP on new or reformatted drives. Another couple of years before I actrually had an UEFI based system. If new motherboard best to think about conversion. Windows will only boot in BIOS from MBR, but Ubuntu can work from either gpt Or MBR.